# fullcalendar-rails installation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm fairly new to Rails and programming in general, and I'm trying to add `fullcalendar-rails` to a fairly basic new application. Unfortunately, the install process seems to fail entirely.

Following the instructions provided at https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails, after ensuring that javascript in general is enabled in the app (making sure I have jquery etc installed), results in an error claiming `$(...).fullCalendar is not a function`. This makes it seem to me that the `fullcalendar` source files are simply not being seen by my Rails app, and I'm not sure how to go about getting them to be seen. I tried manually adding the files to my app structure (in `/lib` and `/vendor`), and that had no effect.

For reference, my `application.js` is this:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
//= require jquery
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "jquery"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
```

UPDATE: following razvans's answer, my `application.js` looks like this:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

import $ from "jquery";
require "moment"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
const calendar = new Calendar(rootEl, {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin]
});

calendar.render();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\prgrm\benkyou\tripplan\tripplan\app\javascript\packs\application.js: Missing semicolon. (12:7)

  10 |
  11 | import $ from "jquery";
> 12 | require "moment"
     |        ^
  13 |
  14 | Rails.start()
  15 | Turbolinks.start()
    at Parser._raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gem is for Asset Pipeline which you don't use. You are on webpacker and inside javascript files you need to use `import/require`. `//= require something` does not work. **Feel free to remove those gems**.

With webpacker you need to add packages with yarn:

```
yarn add @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid
yarn add moment
```

Then import it.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require ("moment")

import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

function loadCalendar() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin]
  });

  calendar.render();
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', loadCalendar);
```

I don't use the library but I tried it just for this. Here's how it looks :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've rolled back to a state before I tried this stuff, added those packages with yarn, and put what you have there into `application.js`, but it's still not working - the `require "moment"` syntax seems to throw an error. Am I putting this in the wrong place? I'm still rather new to all this (^^)

Comment: Please update the question with what you have right now and the error. Add a new section with "UPDATE", don't override the question.

Comment: I have now updated!

Comment: oh sorry, `require('moment')`. I will update. If it works you can remove the "Update" from the question. It's irrelevant now.

Comment: Thank you! Fixing that leaves me with a new error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__k' of null`
    `at S (preact.module.js:341)`

Comment: That's something else I think. Do you get that if you remove the `fullcalendar` code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238143/discussion-between-sjiveru-and-razvans).